# Custom form validation in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a page with some validation checks.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'required_fr');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'omschrijving', 'required');
```

My form_validation_lang.php file looks like this:

```
$lang['required'] = 'Error message 1';
$lang['required_fr'] = 'Error message 2';
```

The required was a standard value, I've added required_fr. If both validation checks fail, I only get 'Error message 1'. The second check (required_fr) doesn't work.

If I edit the 'required' value in the form_validation_lang.php file, the error message changes as well when the form validtion fails. But the 'required_fr' value apparently can't be loaded.

I've also tried putting

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required_fr', 'Error Message 2');
```

in my fucntion, but it doesn't work either.
The solution is probably pretty simple, but I think I'm overlooking something.

The important parts of my page look like this

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo ($this->session->userdata('franstalig') == 0) ? "Categorie" : "Catégorie" ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="ticketCategory" name="category">
                    <option value="">Gelieve een categorie te selecteren</option>
                    <?php if (isset($categories) && !empty($categories)): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>" <?php echo set_select('category', $category['id']); ?>><?php echo $category['description']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketDesc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Omschrijving</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea name="description" id="ticketDesc" class="form-control" rows="16"><?php echo set_value('description'); ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can something be wrong with the validation_errors() function?

Comment: Did you load the language file.

Comment: I did now, but it still isn't working. If 'required_fr' gets called, validation_errors() doesn't show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way.

**Try change:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'required_fr');
```

**To:**

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation_lang');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'required', array('required' => $this->lang->line('required_fr')));
```

Comment: Then I get this: Message: Undefined variable: lang

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I edited, but it still doesn't work. I have no errors anymore, but the validation_errors() still returns 'Error message 1', which is linked to 'required'

Comment: In, `form_validation_lang.php`, `$lang['required_fr']` is still set to `'Error message 2'`?

Comment: Yes. It just shows the error message 1, which is linked to 'required'. Although I have replaced `$this->lang->load('form_validation_lang');` with `$this->lang->load('form_validation');`. If I edit error message 1, the changes apply to my application

Comment: You can change the value of $lang['required_fr'] to 'Error message 2' ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169754/discussion-between-mr-blue-and-walle).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I added

```
public function required_fr($str) 
{
    if ( ! is_array($str))
    {
        return (trim($str) == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ! empty($str));
    }
}
```

to my class, and called `$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'callback_required_fr');`.
That did the trick.